# Generates a list of all possible n-tuples of elements from list

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, permutations, linear-regression

What is the law for the distribution of two elements $\{0, 1\}$ to a set consisting of two elements(`Tuples[{0, 1}, 2]`)

An example can be a way you two distribution $\{0, 1\}$ on a set of two elements, taking into account the order of items.(Permutations)

I know that the probability of ranking will be so,
$$\{\{0, 0\}, \{0, 1\}, \{1, 0\}, \{1, 1\}\}$$
But, what is the mathematical law that formed these totals in the form of last?

What is the law of mathematics that creates the sets,
$$\{\{0, 0\}, \{0, 1\}, \{1, 0\}, \{1, 1\}\}$$
 depending on the distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product).  The reason the Mathematica command is Tuples is that tuples care about order and can have multiple elements the same.  In your last line $\{1,1\}$ is the same set as $\{1\}$ because sets cannot have elements the same.  Also $\{0,1\}=\{1,0\}$ because sets do not care about order.